# C double pointer

Tags: c

```
struct counter{
    long long counter;
}

struct instruction{
    struct counter *counter
    int repetitions;
    void (*work_fn)(long long *);
};

int ncounter; //number of counters
struct counter *counter; //counter array

int nthreads; //number of threads
int *ninstructions; //number of instructions

struct instruction **instructions;
```

How does this actually works ? I am having trouble with `**` pointers

Comment: It might be a good idea to not put the question in a code line comment.

Comment: Please do not tag C questions with C# if you don't know what C# is.

Comment: Please put your question outside the code block otherwise people won't see it. I've edited it and moved it out now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A `**` is just a pointer to a pointer. So where an `instruction*` contains the address of an `instruction` struct, an `instruction**` contains the address of an `instruction*` that contains the address of an `instruction` object.

To access the `instruction` pointed to by the pointer pointed to by an `instruction**`, you just use two asterisks instead of one, like `(**p).repetitions` or something similar.

You can visualize it like this:

```
instruction*  ----> instruction
instruction** ----> instruction* ----> instruction
```

Remember, however, that simply declaring `struct instruction** instructions;` doesn't actually create an `instruction` struct. It just creates a pointer that holds a garbage value. You'll have to initialize it:

```
struct instruction inst;
// set members of inst...
*instructions = &inst;

...

(*instructions)->repetitions++; // or whatever
```

However, it looks like you're using an `instruction**` to point to an array of `instruction*`s. To initialize the array, you need a `for` loop:

```
instructions = malloc(sizeof(struct instruction*) * num_of_arrays);
for (i = 0; i < num_of_arrays; ++i)
    instructions[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct instruction) * size_of_each_subarray);
```

And then you can access an element like `instructions[i]->datamember`.

Comment: but say I use struct counter *counters and made an array. When i access the elements, counter[i]->counters ..... isn't that the same thing?!? but counters are * not **

Comment: @Jono, If you say `struct counter* counters`, that makes a pointer to a `counter`. To access an element, you do `counters[i].something`. `counters[i]` gives you a `counter`. However, if you do `struct counter** counters`, you have to do `counters[i]->something`, notice the `->` instead of the `.`. In this case, `counters[i]` gives you a _pointer_ to a `counter`, not an actual `counter`.

Answer (score 1):

> `struct instruction **instructions; // How does this actually works ? I am having trouble with ** pointers`

I'm not sure what the real issue is, but I'll try to answer the question.

Double pointer is a pointer to pointer. It can be sued as array of pointers for example (if you allocate memory accordingly). For example:

```
instructions = malloc(5*sizeof(struct instruction*));
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    instructions[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct instruction));
```

And you got yourself nice array of 5 pointers to `struct instruction`. Use it like this:

```
instructions[0]->repetitions = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

`instructions` is a pointer to a pointer to `struct instruction`.

This means that `*instructions` will give you a pointer to a `struct instruction`. This kind of construct is often used to create a dynamic array of pointers to some compound type.