# Trouble trying to delete all nodes of value in a linked list

Tags: c++, xcode, pointers, linked-list

I am having trouble trying to delete all of the nodes in a linked list that contain the same integer. I am getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on the commented line below when using the test node: [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 5, 1, 2] and deleted all 2s to get out [1, 1, 3, 1, 5, 1]. Here is my code:

```
int List::RemoveAll(int v) {
    if (IsEmpty())
        return 0;
    else if (HasOnlyOne()) {
        if (h->data == v) {
            delete h;
            h = t = NULL;
            return 1;
        }
    }

    int numRemoved = 0;
    Node *curNode = h->next, *prevNode = h;
    while (curNode != NULL) {
        if (prevNode->data == v) {
            delete prevNode;
            numRemoved++;
        }
        prevNode = curNode;
        curNode = curNode->next; // EXC_BAD_ACCESS error here.
    }

    return numRemoved;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger, while observing the values of the variables?

Comment: You are greatly overcomplicating. Helpful reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12914917/using-pointers-to-remove-item-from-singly-linked-list