# What real use does a double pointer have?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have searched and searched for an answer to this but can't find anything I actually "get".

I am very very new to c++ and can't get my head around the use of double, triple pointers etc.. What is the point of them?

Can anyone enlighten me

Comment: The same as any other pointer

Comment: You need them for 2d arrays, but this is not a good idea in general.

Comment: Don't be a [three star programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer).  Use data structures to encapsulate the pointers.

Comment: _"What is the point of them?"_ Love it

Comment: Here's one: [Using pointers to remove item from singly-linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12914917/using-pointers-to-remove-item-from-singly-linked-list)

Comment: If you are in modern C++ and not C, you rarely need to have any pointers because it has nicer alternatives like references, various constructs in the standard library like std::vector, std::list, etc., and when those don't work, std::unique_ptr and std::shared_ptr. For plain old C, I recall there are cases when a double pointer is useful when dealing with linked lists (e.g. having a pointer to the "next" pointer field made some code handling the list simpler).

Comment: @Dave: On the contrary, those are more complicated and less clear alternatives to simple and obvious pointers.  As for instance what's probably the most common instance of a double pointer (in C): "int main (int argc, char **argv)".

Comment: It’s unfortunate that every beginner sees `argv` early, because it sets a very bad example.

Comment: One **non**-answer to your question: nobody’s saying that ragged arrays are a good solution when the rows of a matrix contain different amounts of data and you want to save space. If you ever need to do that, make sure you at least consider *compressed sparse row* representation.

Comment: So, @MarkGreen, did you get your answer?

Comment: I got a lot of answers and am processing it all  c is definitely a complex language with a steep learning curve.

Answer (score 53):

Honestly, in well-written C++ you should very rarely see a `T**` outside of library code. In fact, the more stars you have, the closer you are to winning [an award of a certain nature](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer).

That's not to say that a pointer-to-pointer is never called for; you may need to construct a pointer to a pointer for the same reason that you ever need to construct a pointer to any other type of object.

In particular, I might expect to see such a thing inside a data structure or algorithm implementation, when you're shuffling around dynamically allocated nodes, perhaps?

Generally, though, outside of this context, *if* you need to pass around a reference to a pointer, you'd do just that (i.e. `T*&`) rather than doubling up on pointers, and even that ought to be fairly rare.

On Stack Overflow you're going to see people doing ghastly things with pointers to arrays of dynamically allocated pointers to data, trying to implement the least efficient "2D vector" they can think of. Please don't be inspired by them.

In summary, your intuition is not without merit.

Comment: _"In fact, the more stars you have, the closer you are to winning an award of a certain nature."_ - +1ed for that one sentence.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah: Now if people +1 for each of the other sentences, I'll be doing alright!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You should then end every word with a period to maximize the upvote potential ;)

Comment: @NathanOliver: Could do, but I still haven't won the war against comma splices and am not quite ready to start one on period splices :D

Comment: Anyone who disagrees with the notion of a "three star programmer" should have a look at the [API for (one of?) the most widely deployed SQL engines in the world](http://sqlite.org/capi3ref.html). There is only one function that has a `***` argument, and it's part of a legacy interface.

Comment: Some numbers: The project I am currently working on has ~892,000 lines (for simplicity, I counted all lines, including blanks and brace-only lines). 39 occurrences of references to pointers `*&`. About 70 occurrences of pointers to pointers (this is harder to count of course, many false positives on `**`), but almost all of them are in a C compatibility module, with `assert( p != NULL )`, and could therefore be replaced by `*&` in "pure" C++.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar: And even then, we are talking about a **C** API. In C++ there are references and higher-level pointer types which seriously reduce the need for multiple stars.

Comment: @MatthieuM. : Of course. I forgot to mention that it's strictly a C API. I wholeheartedly agree with you.

Answer (score 16):

An important reason why you should/must know about pointer-to-pointer-... is that you sometimes have to interface with other languages (like C for instance) through some API (for instance the Windows API).

Those APIs often have functions that have an output-parameter that returns a pointer. However those other languages often don't have references or compatible (with C++) references. That's a situation when pointer-to-pointer is needed.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I only want to understand the use of them. I will avoid them unless I find a use.

Answer (score 13):

It's less used in c++. However, in C, it can be very useful. Say that you have a function that will malloc some random amount of memory and fill the memory with some stuff. It would be a pain to have to call a function to get the size you need to allocate and then call another function that will fill the memory. Instead you can use a double pointer. The double pointer allows the function to set the pointer to the memory location. There are some other things it can be used for but that's the best thing I can think of.

```
int func(char** mem){
    *mem = malloc(50);
    return 50;
}

int main(){
    char* mem = NULL;
    int size = func(&mem);
    free(mem);
}
```

Comment: Since the question is tagged with C++ your argument really doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @NathanOliver This is almost valid C++ (it's missing a cast). And it's not even useless C++ code - it may be used when interoperating with C.

Comment: A real-world example of this: `posix_memalign()`.

Comment: I also think that explaining why double pointers are useful in C *is useful* to understanding what they do in C++, even if C++ does offer other ways to do the same things.

Answer (score 12):

> I am very very new to c++ and can't get my head around the use of double, triple pointers etc.. What is the point of them?

The trick to understanding pointers in C is simply to go back to the basics, which you were probably never taught.  They are:

- Variables store values of a particular type.
- Pointers are a kind of value.
- If `x` is a variable of type `T` then `&x` is a value of type `T*`.
- If `x` evaluates to a value of type `T*` then `*x` is a variable of type `T`. More specifically...
- ... if `x` evaluates to a value of type `T*` that is equal to `&a` for some variable `a` of type `T`, then `*x` is an alias for `a`.

Now everything follows:

```
int x = 123;
```

`x` is a variable of type `int`.  Its value is `123`.

```
int* y = &x;
```

`y` is a variable of type `int*`. `x` is a variable of type `int`.  So `&x` is a value of type `int*`. Therefore we can store `&x` in `y`.

```
*y = 456;
```

`y` evaluates to the contents of variable `y`. That's a value of type `int*`.  Applying `*` to a value of type `int*` gives a **variable** of type `int`.  Therefore we can assign 456 to it.  What is `*y`?  It is an alias for `x`.  Therefore we have just assigned 456 to `x`.

```
int** z = &y;
```

What is `z`? It's a variable of type `int**`.  What is `&y`? Since `y` is a variable of type `int*`, `&y` must be a value of type `int**`. Therefore we can assign it to `z`.

```
**z = 789;
```

What is `**z`?  Work from the inside out. `z` evaluates to an `int**`.  Therefore `*z` is a variable of type `int*`.  It is an alias for `y`.  Therefore this is the same as `*y`, and we already know what that is; it's an alias for `x`.

> No really, what's the point?

Here, I have a piece of paper. It says `1600 Pennsylvania Avenue Washington DC`.  Is that a house? No, it's a piece of paper with the address of a house written on it.  But we can use that piece of paper to *find* the house.

Here, I have ten million pieces of paper, all numbered.  Paper number 123456 says `1600 Pennsylvania Avenue`. Is 123456 a house?  No. Is it a piece of paper? No.  But it is still *enough information for me to find the house*.

That's the point: *often we need to refer to entities through multiple levels of indirection for convenience*.

That said, double pointers are confusing and a sign that your algorithm is insufficiently abstract.  Try to avoid them by using good design techniques.

Comment: @Tas: That was a typo. Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: 2nd to last paragraph: Exactly.  Since the solution to any problem in computer science is to add another level of indirection, seeing a double pointer just means someone got to that problem first, and solved it.

Comment: @davidbak there is one problem that doesn't work for. What is it?

Comment: Umm ... the thing that the "." operator in BLISS-16 is used for?  (BLISS-32 had it too ...)

Comment: @davidbak "I have too many layers of abstraction."

Answer (score 10):

A double-pointer, is simply a pointer to a pointer.  A common usage is for arrays of character strings.  Imagine the first function in just about every  C/C++ program:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   ...
}
```

Which can also be written

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   ...
}
```

The variable *argv* is a pointer to an array of pointers to char.  This is a standard way of passing around arrays of C "strings".  Why do that?  I've seen it used for multi-language support, blocks of error strings, etc.

Don't forget that a pointer is just a number - the index of the memory "slot"  inside a computer.  That's it, nothing more.   So a double-pointer is index of a piece of memory that just happens to hold another index to somewhere else.  A mathematical join-the-dots if you like.

This is how I explained pointers to my kids:

Imagine the computer memory is a series of boxes.  Each box has a number written on it, starting at zero, going up by 1, to however many bytes of memory there is.  Say you have a pointer to some place in memory.  This pointer is just the box number.  My pointer is, say 4.  I look into box #4.  Inside is another number, this time it's 6.  So now we look into box #6, and get the final thing we wanted.  My original pointer (that said "4") was a double-pointer, because the content of its box was the index of another box, rather than being a final result.

It seems in recent times pointers themselves have become a pariah of programming.   Back in the not-too-distant past, it was completely normal to pass around pointers to pointers.  But with the proliferation of Java, and increasing use of pass-by-reference in C++, the fundamental understanding of pointers declined - particularly around when Java became established as a first-year computer science beginners language, over say Pascal and C.

I think a lot of the venom about pointers is because people just don't ever understand them properly. Things people don't understand get derided.  So they became "too hard" and "too dangerous".  I guess with even supposedly learned people advocating [Smart Pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer), etc. these ideas are to be expected.  But in reality there a very powerful programming tool.  Honestly, pointers are the magic of programming, and after-all, they're just a number.

Answer (score 1):

In many situations, a `Foo*&` is a replacement for a `Foo**`.  In both cases, you have a pointer whose address can be modified.

Suppose you have an abstract non-value type and you need to return it, but the return value is taken up by the error code:

```
error_code get_foo( Foo** ppfoo )
```

or

```
error_code get_foo( Foo*& pfoo_out )
```

Now a function argument being mutable is rarely useful, so the ability to change where the *outermost* pointer `ppFoo` points at is rarely useful. However, a pointer is *nullable* -- so if `get_foo`'s argument is *optional*, a pointer acts like an optional reference.

In this case, the return value is a raw pointer.  If it returns an owned resource, it should usually be instead a `std::unique_ptr<Foo>*` -- a smart pointer at that level of indirection.

If instead, it is returning a pointer to something it does not share ownership of, then a raw pointer makes more sense.

There are other uses for `Foo**` besides these "crude out parameters".  If you have a polymorphic non-value type, non-owning handles are `Foo*`, and the same reason why you'd want to have an `int*` you would want to have a `Foo**`.

Which then leads you to ask "why do you want an `int*`?"  In modern C++ `int*` is a non-owning nullable mutable reference to an `int`.  It behaves better when stored in a `struct` than a reference does (references in structs generate confusing semantics around assignment and copy, especially if mixed with non-references).

You could sometimes replace `int*` with `std::reference_wrapper<int>`, well `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<int>>`, but note that is going to be 2x as large as a simple `int*`.

So there are legitimate reasons to use `int*`.  Once you have that, you can legitimately use `Foo**` when you want a pointer to a non-value type.  You can even get to `int**` by having a contiguous array of `int*`s you want to operate on.

Legitimately getting to three-star programmer gets harder.  Now you need a legitimate reason to (say) want to pass a `Foo**` by indirection.  Usually long before you reach that point, you should have considered abstracting and/or simplifying your code structure.

All of this ignores the most common reason; interacting with C APIs.  C doesn't have `unique_ptr`, it doesn't have `span`.  It tends to use primitive types instead of structs because structs require awkward function based access (no operator overloading).

So when C++ interacts with C, you sometimes get 0-3 more `*`s than the equivalent C++ code would.

Comment: I cannot follow the logic. E.g. how is `std::unique_ptr<Foo>*` useful, and why you are talking about returning it, while you already occupied return type with error code?

Comment: @Mikhail `error_code get_foo( std::unique_ptr<Foo>* here )` "returns" its "return value" through a pointer argument, while its actual return is taken up by `error_code`.  This pattern is fromalized in stuff like COM and IDL, where exceptions are not used and semantic return values are always pointers, while syntactic return values are error codes.

Answer (score 0):

The use is to have a pointer to a pointer, e.g., if you want to pass a pointer to a method by reference.

Comment: C++ has references though so `foo(type*&)` should be preferred.

Comment: May be better stated:  if you want the function to modify the value in a pointer, pass the address of a pointer (or in C++, pass pointer by reference).

Answer (score 0):

In C++, if you want to pass a pointer as an out or in/out parameter, you pass it by reference:

```
int x;
void f(int *&p) { p = &x; }
```

But, a reference can't ("legally") be `nullptr`, so, if the pointer is optional, you need a pointer to a pointer:

```
void g(int **p) { if (p) *p = &x; }
```

Sure, since C++17 you have `std::optional`, but, the "double pointer" has been idiomatic C/C++ code for many decades, so should be OK. Also, the usage is not so nice, you either:

```
void h(std::optional<int*> &p) { if (p) *p = &x) }
```

which is kind of ugly at the call site, unless you already have a `std::optional`, or:

```
void u(std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<int*>> p) { if (p) p->get() = &x; }
```

which is not so nice in itself.

Also, some might argue that `g` is nicer to read at the call site:

```
f(p);
g(&p); // `&` indicates that `p` might change, to some folks
```

Comment: But you wouldn't pass a raw pointer as an out or in/out parameter in C++, not really. That's the point. If you have control of the design, it's better to design it in some other way.

Comment: Also there is no such thing as C/C++ and just because this style was used decades ago doesn't mean it should be used now.

Comment: Please don't read much into `C/C++`, it's just a common way to indicate "C and/or C++". Also, the question was "what's the point of them", not "should I use them".

Comment: How are you going to use `std::optional` in your example?

Answer (score 0):

> What real use does a double pointer have?

Here is practical example. Say you have a function and you want to send an array of string params to it (maybe you have a DLL you want to pass params to). This can look like this:

```
#include <iostream>

void printParams(const char **params, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << params[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    const char *params[] = { "param1", "param2", "param3" };
    printParams(params, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

You will be sending an array of `const char` pointers, each pointer pointing to the start of a null terminated C string. The compiler will decay your array into pointer at function argument, hence what you get is `const char **` a pointer to first pointer of array of `const char` pointers. Since the array size is lost at this point, you will want to pass it as second argument.

Comment: This is not C++, this is "C with iostreams".

Comment: `std::vector<std::string>`

Answer (score 0):

One case where I've used it is a function manipulating a linked list, in C.

There is

```
struct node { struct node *next; ... };
```

for the list nodes, and

```
struct node *first;
```

to point to the first element. All the manipulation functions take a `struct node **`, because I can guarantee that this pointer is non-`NULL` even if the list is empty, and I don't need any special cases for insertion and deletion:

```
void link(struct node *new_node, struct node **list)
{
    new_node->next = *list;
    *list = new_node;
}

void unlink(struct node **prev_ptr)
{
    *prev_ptr = (*prev_ptr)->next;
}
```

To insert at the beginning of the list, just pass a pointer to the `first` pointer, and it will do the right thing even if the value of `first` is `NULL`.

```
struct node *new_node = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof *new_node);
link(new_node, &first);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be better expressed by defining a `struct list { struct node * head; };`? Then you take a `struct list *`. As a bonus, should you at some point need to store more stuff (eg: list length, or tail pointer), you won't have to change all your signatures.

Comment: @spectras, that would still require me to either special-case insertion of the first element, or form a pointer-to-pointer. I'm using pointer-to-pointer in that implementation because it allows me to insert in arbitrary places.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple indirection is largely a holdover from C (which has neither reference nor container types).  You shouldn't see multiple indirection that much in well-written C++, unless you're dealing with a legacy C library or something like that.

Having said that, multiple indirection falls out of some fairly common use cases.

In both C and C++, array expressions will "decay" from type "N-element array of `T`" to "pointer to `T`" under most circumstances<sup>1</sup>.  So, assume an array definition like

```
T *a[N]; // for any type T
```

When you pass `a` to a function, like so:

```
foo( a );
```

the *expression* `a` will be converted from "N-element array of `T *`" to "pointer to `T *`", or `T **`, so what the function actually receives is

```
void foo( T **a ) { ... }
```

A second place they pop up is when you want a function to modify a parameter of pointer type, something like

```
void foo( T **ptr )
{
  *ptr = new_value();
}

void bar( void )
{
  T *val;
  foo( &val );
}
```

Since C++ introduced references, you probably won't see that as often. You'll usually only see that when working with a C-based API.

You can also use multiple indirection to set up "jagged" arrays, but you can achieve the same thing with C++ containers for *much* less pain.  But if you're feeling masochistic:

```
T **arr;

try
{
  arr = new T *[rows];
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    arr[i] = new T [size_for_row(i)];
}
catch ( std::bad_alloc& e )
{
  ...
}
```

But most of the time in C++, the only time you should see multiple indirection is when an array of pointers "decays" to a pointer expression itself.

---

1. The exceptions to this rule occur when the expression is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize another array in a declaration.

Comment: Re, "C ...[has no] container types."  You mean, the C _standard library_ has none.  After all, there's no container types in the C++ language either:  Those are all implemented by library routines.  Anyway, nothing ever stopped a smart C programmer from implementing his/her own container types, and nothing ever stopped an even smarter programmer from using container implementations that somebody else already implemented and debugged.  (Though, to be fair, I didn't know to call them "containers" until decades later, after I started working in Java.)