# Issue with class inside class

Tags: c++, class, matrix

Being a bit curious about machine learning, I have started reading some introductory tutorials related to that topic. Due to this, some days ago I found a very simple neural network example, implemented using Python with the `numpy` library and for practicing purposes, I decided to implement the same algorithm using C++ with as less as possible external libraries.

Then, I first coded a simple class able to handle matrix definitions/declarations and related mathematical operations like addition, multiplication, etc. I eloquently named that class as `Matrix`.
Here is its header file:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix {
public:
  Matrix(int numRows, int numColumns);
  ~Matrix();
  int getRows();
  int getColumns();
  T readValue(int row, int column);
  void writeValue(int row, int column, T value);
  Matrix<T> operator+(Matrix<T> other);
  Matrix<T> operator-(Matrix<T> other);
  Matrix<T> operator*(T scalar);
  Matrix<T> operator*(Matrix<T> other);
  Matrix<T> entrywiseProduct(Matrix<T> other);
  Matrix<T> transpose();
  void print();
private:
  const int rows;
  const int columns;
  T** matrix;
};
```

As you can see, in order to allocate the right memory size, I decided to let the class constructor need two different arguments, that is number of rows and columns.

Anyway, after the definition of this briefly explained class, I started to code the main class for the network implementation. In particular, this more abstract class will mainly use the `Matrix` class for most of the operations. Here is the header:

```
#include "Matrix.h"

template <typename T>
class Neuron {
public:
  Neuron(int matrixRows, int matrixColumns);
  ~Neuron();
  Matrix<T> estimate(Matrix<T> inputMatrix);
  void train(Matrix<T> inputMatrix, Matrix<T> outputMatrix, int iterations);
private:
  Matrix<T> weights;
};
```

Despite it is not properly elegant, also this class constructor takes two input parameters related to matrices: that is because they will be used to correctly instantiate a matrix inside the class for the weighting coefficient storage.

And here is the issue: the mentioned matrix should be definitely instantiated after the initialisation of the `Neuron` class. As far as I know, this kind of operation requires the utilisation of a pointer which will be referred by the `new` function, used - on its side - to dynamically instantiate a `Matrix` class, in this case. However, on the other side, I have decided that operations with matrices always returns a new matrix and not a pointer to matrix, as you can see in the first class header.

So, I am going to ask you: is it possible to define a matrix inside the `Neuron` constructor and use it as a class variable, as defined in the previous header? In this way, I should be able to overwrite the same variable when doing operations on the `weights` named matrix.
If yes, how can I do this?

Comment: Recommend a read of [What is the Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) to prevent some nasty debugging in the future. While you're at it, familiarize yourself with its companions the [Rules of Zero and Five.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes; initialise your matrix like you *should* be initialising any other class member: in the constructor's [member initialisation list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1711990/560648).

```
Neuron::Neuron(int matrixRows, int matrixColumns)
   : weights(matrixRows, matrixColumns)
{}
```

When you do this:

```
T::T()
{
   member = firstValue;
}
```

that is not initialisation, it is assignment. You are correct when you say that this is insufficient if the member's type has no default constructor, because if you don't initialise a member yourself the compiler will try to initialise it for you, and it can't provide arguments it doesn't know about. The smart pointer/dynamic allocation is a common workaround if you *can't* properly initialise your member for some reason (for example, information needs to be gathered first).

By the way, `T**` suggests you're creating an array of pointers. [Don't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49015885/560648); it's very inefficient and overly complex. Just create an array of width×height `T`s instead and map indexes accordingly (i = y×width + x; x = i % width; y = i / width).

Comment: I've sometimes used fields like `std::optional<Matrix<T>>` as an alternative workaround for cases where there was a more valid reason to defer initialization of the member, but still wanted its storage to be allocated within the parent object instead of on the heap.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: Not bad.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, thank you so much for your useful suggestions. Anyway, I have updated now my question because something is going wrong.

Comment: @rudicangiotti: That's a completely different question. Please don't transform your questions. Post a new one.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, sorry for that but I thought it was a issue related to the topics of the question's first comment. Anyway, I am going to post a new question.