# How to delete element from array by pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I want to delete n'th element from array and when I use for loop I want program to print all numbers by sequence except that n'th element. 
Ex. `4 7 6 2 9 5`.

If I want to delete the 2nd element then after deleting I want to print `4 7 2 9 5` and I don't want to move every element to left.

Is it possible using `free()` or pointers?

Please explain me, I'm new in pointer programming.

Comment: No it's not possible without moving the elements in the array, an array doesn't have any "holes" in it. It's not even possible with an array allocated dynamically with e.g. `malloc`. Perhaps arrays is the wrong kind of data-structure whatever problem you want to solve?

Comment: When you mean delete, you mean equal to 0 or suppress the element or only not printing it ?

Comment: I think what you really want is a [linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12914917).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just remove an element of an array using `free()` You have to opt for Data structures like Linked List in order to do such operations!
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-3-deleting-node/
Try this !

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible if the data is a C array of integers, e.g.:

```
int array[10];
```

However, if you used another data structure, like a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list), it is possible to remove an element without moving the rest.

Comment: linked list may be tricky of he does not know how to use free =).