# Append an element to the end of a Circular Linked List with this particular function

Tags: c, list, linked-list, circular-list

I'll try to be as clear as I can.

I have this struct (and I can't change it because of my teachers) in a file called "esercizio.h":

```
#ifndef ESERCIZIO_H
#define ESERCIZIO_H

struct ElemSCL{
    int info;
    struct ElemSCL* next;
};

typedef struct ElemSCL NodoSCL;
typedef NodoSCL* TipoSCL;

void accoda(TipoSCL* pscl, int i);
#endif
```

The function "accoda" must add an element (int i) to the end of a circular linked list (pointed by TipoSCL* pscl). I have tried to write the function body in a file called "esercizio.c":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "esercizio.h"

void accoda(TipoSCL* pscl, int i){
    NodoSCL* temp = (NodoSCL*) malloc(sizeof(NodoSCL));
    temp->info = i;
    temp->next = temp;
    if (pscl == NULL){
        return;}
    while ((*pscl)->next != *pscl){
        *pscl = (*pscl)->next;}
    (*temp)->next = (*pscl)->next; //Problems starts here
    (*pscl)->next = *temp;
    }
```

As I let you notice in my code, everything is ok if I don't add the lasts two rows. If in the function there was not TypeSCL* but NodeSCL* I would use:

```
temp->next = pscl->next;
pscl->next = temp;}
```

But my teacher decided to use TypeSCL* pscl instead of NodeSCL* pscl.

I have a "test.h" file...

```
#include "esercizio.h"

#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

char* toString(TipoSCL scl);

#endif
```

... and a "test.c" file, with the main() function and all the inputs which let me check if my code is working:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "../libtest/libtest.h"
#include "test.h"
#include "esercizio.h"


const int NTEST=5;

TipoSCL input[5];
int add[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
TipoSCL expected[5];


int main(int argc, char** argv){


    input[0] = NULL;

    input[1] = (TipoSCL) malloc(sizeof(NodoSCL));
    input[1] -> info = 1;
    input[1] -> next = input[1];

    input[2] = (TipoSCL) malloc(sizeof(NodoSCL));
    input[2] -> info = 1;
    input[2] -> next = (TipoSCL) malloc(sizeof(NodoSCL));
    input[2] -> next -> info = 2;
    input[2] -> next -> next = input[2];

    input[3] = (TipoSCL) malloc(sizeof(NodoSCL));
    input[3] -> info = 1;
    input[3] -> next = (TipoSCL) malloc(sizeof(NodoSCL));
    input[3] -> next -> info = 2;
    input[3] -> next -> next = (TipoSCL) malloc(sizeof(NodoSCL));
    input[3] -> next -> next -> info = 3;
    input[3] -> next -> next -> next = input[3];

    input[4] = (TipoSCL) malloc(sizeof(NodoSCL));
    input[4] -> info = 1;
    input[4] -> next = (TipoSCL) malloc(sizeof(NodoSCL));
    input[4] -> next -> info = 2;
    input[4] -> next -> next = (TipoSCL) malloc(sizeof(NodoSCL));
    input[4] -> next -> next -> info = 3;
    input[4] -> next -> next -> next = (TipoSCL) malloc(sizeof(NodoSCL));
    input[4] -> next -> next -> next -> info = 4;
    input[4] -> next -> next -> next -> next = input[4];

    expected[0] = (TipoSCL) malloc(sizeof(NodoSCL));
    expected[0] -> info = 1;
    expected[0] -> next = expected[0];

    expected[1] = (TipoSCL) malloc(sizeof(NodoSCL));
    expected[1] -> info = 1;
    expected[1] -> next = (TipoSCL) malloc(sizeof(NodoSCL));
    expected[1] -> next -> info = 2;
    expected[1] -> next -> next = expected[1];

    expected[2] = (TipoSCL) malloc(sizeof(NodoSCL));
    expected[2] -> info = 1;
    expected[2] -> next = (TipoSCL) malloc(sizeof(NodoSCL));
    expected[2] -> next -> info = 2;
    expected[2] -> next -> next = (TipoSCL) malloc(sizeof(NodoSCL));
    expected[2] -> next -> next -> info = 3;
    expected[2] -> next -> next -> next = expected[2];

    expected[3] = (TipoSCL) malloc(sizeof(NodoSCL));
    expected[3] -> info = 1;
    expected[3] -> next = (TipoSCL) malloc(sizeof(NodoSCL));
    expected[3] -> next -> info = 2;
    expected[3] -> next -> next = (TipoSCL) malloc(sizeof(NodoSCL));
    expected[3] -> next -> next -> info = 3;
    expected[3] -> next -> next -> next = (TipoSCL) malloc(sizeof(NodoSCL));
    expected[3] -> next -> next -> next -> info = 4;
    expected[3] -> next -> next -> next -> next = expected[3];

    expected[4] = (TipoSCL) malloc(sizeof(NodoSCL));
    expected[4] -> info = 1;
    expected[4] -> next = (TipoSCL) malloc(sizeof(NodoSCL));
    expected[4] -> next -> info = 2;
    expected[4] -> next -> next = (TipoSCL) malloc(sizeof(NodoSCL));
    expected[4] -> next -> next -> info = 3;
    expected[4] -> next -> next -> next = (TipoSCL) malloc(sizeof(NodoSCL));
    expected[4] -> next -> next -> next -> info = 4;
    expected[4] -> next -> next -> next -> next = (TipoSCL) malloc(sizeof(NodoSCL));
    expected[4] -> next -> next -> next -> next -> info = 5;
    expected[4] -> next -> next -> next -> next  -> next = expected[4];




    test_reset();

    for (int i = 0; i < NTEST; i++) {
        print_test_start(i+1);
        printf("Funzione: accoda\n");
        printf("Input: %s\n", toString(input[i]));

        accoda(&input[i],add[i]);

        test_compare_strings(toString(expected[i]),toString(input[i]));

        print_test_end();
        print_n_success("#Test superati: ");
    }
    print_test_result("Percentuale test corretti:");
}


char* toString(TipoSCL scl){
    char* res = (char*) malloc(200*sizeof(char));
    res[0] = '[';
    res[1] = '\0';
    TipoSCL aux = scl;
    if (aux != NULL) {
        char buf[10];
        do{
            sprintf(buf,"%d->",aux -> info);
            strcat(res,buf);
            aux = aux -> next;
        }
        while(aux != scl);
        sprintf(buf,"|%d",aux -> info);
        strcat(res,buf);
        aux = aux -> next;
    }
    strcat(res,"]");
    return res;
}
```

**What I mean with "everything is ok if I don't add the lasts two rows" to my code?**
When I run my program (thanks to terminal and *cd*  and *make* ) without

```
(*temp)->next = (*pscl)->next; //Problems starts here
(*pscl)->next = *temp;
```

the test run without problem (but of course, it say me that I have no one right result. But if I add this two rows to my code, I got "Segmentation fault: 11".

Comment: Depending on how you call `add`, `*pscl` might point to the *head* of the list. Besides that, when you say that "things go wrong...", what do you mean by that? Can you please elaborate? Do you get build errors? Runtime errors? Unexpected behavior? What? And please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, including how you call the `add` function and what arguments you pass.

Comment: `temp->next = temp;` this line is unnecessary since the next thing you do is change temp->next again. Also, since *pscl is also a pointer, it'd be good to check if that is null. I'd change `if(pscl == NULL) ` to `if(pscl == NULL || *pscl == NULL)`

Comment: Standard warning: Do not cast `void *` as used by `malloc` & friends.

Comment: It is in general a bad idea to create a type for a pointer. That makes code more complicate to read and adds to the confusion, as you have to remember about the additional indirection. It is better to add the `*` explicitly for pointer variables.

Comment: Well if you have to add to the end to list, shouldn't you  be using a while loop to traverse till the last node?? The list might get longer than size 2

Comment: Further, you cannot just use `NodeSCL *`, if I am understanding typedef correctly, then `TTypeSCL* pscl` is same as `NodeSCL **pscl`, probably that is why your teacher denied for it. You cannot add to a linked list, without a double pointer (in your case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your add function to this ::

```
void add(TypeSCL* pscl, int i){
    NodeSCL* temp = (NodeSCL*) malloc(sizeof(NodeSCL));
    temp->info = i;
    temp->next = temp;
    if (*pscl == NULL){
    *pscl = temp;
        return;} 
    NodeSCL *tempCheck = *pscl;
    while(tempCheck->next != *pscl) {
        tempCheck = tempCheck->next;
    }
    tempCheck->next = temp;
    temp->next = (*pscl); 
}
```

Things you do wrong ::
You need to realize everything in C is passed by value, so if you pass a pointer, that pointer is also passed by value. So, when you teacher tells you to use `TypeSCL* pscl` it means `NodeSCL **pscl`, and she is right, because you cannot do it with `NodeSCL *pscl`, this might help you understand why I say this :: [What is the reason for using a double pointer when adding a node in a linked list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271647/what-is-the-reason-for-using-a-double-pointer-when-adding-a-node-in-a-linked-lis)

Further, in your case when `pscl == NULL` first it should be `*pscl == NULL` you need to set your `*pscl` to you new node.

Next, if you want to add a new node at the end, you shall use a while loop, as mentioned by @Neha Chauhan.

Next, the last two statements that you used ::

```
(*temp)->next = (*pscl)->next;
(*pscl)->next = *temp;
```

You are setting the `next` of your newly added node to the 2nd element of you linked list, which doesn't make any sense.

I have used the variable `NodeSCL *tempCheck` to move to the last node of the linked list!

So, the last 2 lines shall look like

```
tempCheck->next = temp;
temp->next = (*pscl);
```

Lastly, bro you need to work up on your basics with pointers. (Don't Mind!)

**EDIT::**

Why your test works without the last 2 lines :: Because, with the code you have written, your linked list is always of size 1, no elements are added after the first element! So, the test runs, but it fails!

Comment: Thank you, bro, now the program works properly!
I'll try to see some guide about pointers, I'm actually confused.

Comment: Check the link I mentioned, that might help!

Comment: Thank you again! P.S. cout was used undeclared, so I deleted the row 'cout << temp->info <<"\n";', because I have no idea of what cout is...

Comment: `cout` is used to print on terminal in c++, left it there by mistake while debugging!

Answer (score 0):

i think your pscl pointer must go till end of the linklist and then it shoul insert the temp element .
what you can do is

```
    void add(TypeSCL* pscl, int i){
    NodeSCL* temp = (NodeSCL*) malloc(sizeof(NodeSCL));
    temp->info = i;
    temp->next = temp;
    if (pscl == NULL){
    return;
    while(pscl->next != pscl)
    pscl = pscl->next;
    temp->next = (*pscl)->next; //THINGS GO WRONG HERE...
    (*pscl)->next = temp;       //...AND HERE
     }
```

'