# Use of ** in BST insert( )

Tags: c, pointers, binary-search-tree

The following is my code for BST insert function.Could someone explain why this gives a segmentation fault?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int value;
    struct node* right;
    struct node* left;
};

struct node* insert(struct node* n,int age){
    if (n==NULL){
        n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));   
        n->value = age;
        n->left = n->right = NULL; 
    }
    else if(age < n->value){ 
        n->left = insert(n->left, age);
    }
    else {
        n->right = insert(n->right, age);
    }
    return n;
}

void main(){
    int age;
    struct node* n=NULL;
    scanf("%d",&age);
    while (age!=-1){
        n=insert(n,age);    
        scanf("%d",&age);
    }
}
```

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35021521/what-does-do-in-c-language) and it suggests the use of ** (reference to pointer).

```
f( &px );
//...

void f( int **px )
{
    *px = malloc( sizeof( int ) );

    printf( "*px = %p\n", *px );
}
```

But why can't we avoid the use of ** by changing the return type from `void` to `node*`?

Comment: `insert` always crashes. Doesn't your compiler warn for this?

Comment: `main` should return `int`, not `void`.

Comment: You're missing `#include <stdlib.h>` and `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: Don't use `scanf` for user input (but if you do, always check its return value).

Comment: What does your debugger say where the crash is?

Comment: `if (n=NULL){` --> `if (n==NULL){` and need `return n;` end of `insert`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Does the position of return statement matter? I didn't get any compilation error.Yet,I made the changes and tried but didn't get the output.

Comment: @melpomene The compilation was clean.No errors or warnings. Why would `insert()` crash?

Comment: `insert ` must return `struct node*`. So, `return` is necessary.

Comment: BTW Do not change posting code without annotation. because matching with questions and answers is lost.

Comment: _didn't get the output_  Because you are not printing anything.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thank you.I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: By not getting output i meant, the code doesn't even accept values and work the way it should.When I run the code, it gives `segmentation fault(core dumped)` and exits.

Comment: @AlekhyaVellanki Because `n=NULL` assigns `NULL` to `n` and then the following `n->value` dereferences a null pointer. What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me. I didn't change much or your code, except for how you are using `scanf()`, which doesn't end when you enter `1`.

It is better to just call `scanf` once, and make sure you allow continuous input, using `while (scanf(.....) == 1`, to make sure that one value is always read until terminated, in this case, until `age` is `1`.

Unless I am missing something, this is the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int value;
    struct node* right;
    struct node* left;
};

struct node* insert(struct node* n,int age){
    if (n==NULL){
        n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));   
        n->value = age;
        n->left = n->right = NULL; 
    }
    else if(age < n->value){ 
        n->left = insert(n->left, age);
    }
    else {
        n->right = insert(n->right, age);
    }
    return n;
}

void
print_tree(struct node *n) {
    if (n != NULL) {
        print_tree(n->left);
        printf("%d\n", n->value);
        print_tree(n->right);
    }
}

int main(){
    int age;
    struct node* n = NULL;

    printf("Enter some numbers(1 to stop): ");
    while (scanf("%d", &age) == 1 && age != 1) {
        n = insert(n, age);
    }

    printf("\nYour numbers inserted into BST:\n");
    print_tree(n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just changed my `void main()` to `int main()` and it works.Thanks!.But I fail to understand why `void` didn't work.

Comment: This answer does not seem to fix any segfault.  The code in the question, as it now stands, seems to be correct.  Using `scanf` in the way that @RoadRunner suggests is a good idea, but not necessary.