# Using Double Pointers in Memory Location

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference, function-declaration, function-parameter

I'm trying to understand purpose and how it's works double pointer in this code.

Why we use `**p` in the declaring function but inside the function we used `*p`?

```
void allocate(int** p)
{
  *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
}

int main()
{
  int *p = NULL;
  allocate(&p);
  *p = 42;
}
```

Comment: `**p` is a pointer to a pointer, so  `*p` is a pointer to `p`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35021864/15160601

Comment: `int **` is a "pointer to pointer to int".  `double *` is a double pointer.

Comment: `int**` is conceptually the same as `int*` except that the address it holds is that of an `int*` instead of an `int`. If you understand the example after removing one level of pointer everywhere then understanding this example is the same process. If you don't understand the simpler version, I'd recommend studying that instead.

Answer (score 1):

The function's parameter `p` has type pointer-to-pointer to `int`, i.e. `int **`.  So referring to `p` refers to an object of that type.

The expression `*p` *dereferences* `p` giving you an expression (which is also an *lvalue*) of type `int *`.  This matches the type of `p` in the `main` function, and actually refers to that object.  This allows us, inside the function `allocate`, to modify the value of `p` in `main` to contain the address of a dynamically allocated block of memory.

Answer (score 0):

To change the original pointer `p` declared within the function `main` in function `allocate` you need to pass it by reference. Otherwise the function will deal with a copy of the value of the original pointer `p` and changing the copy will not influence on the value stored in the original pointer.

In C passing by reference means passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it. So dereferencing the pointer you will get an access to the original object.

Consider the following demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( int x )
{
    x = 20;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int x = 10;
    
    printf( "Before calling the function d c = %d\n", x );
    
    f( x );
    
    printf( "After  calling the function d c = %d\n", x );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Before calling the function d c = 10
After  calling the function d c = 10
```

As you can see the original variable `x` was not changed after calling the function f because the variable is passed by value to the function.

Now consider the following program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( int *px )
{
    *px = 20;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int x = 10;
    
    printf( "Before calling the function d c = %d\n", x );
    
    f( &x );
    
    printf( "After  calling the function d c = %d\n", x );

    return 0;
}
```

At this time the program output is

```
Before calling the function d c = 10
After  calling the function d c = 20
```

As the variable `x` was passed by reference then dereferencing the pointer
`px`

```
*px = 20;
```

you get a direct access to the original variable `x` through the pointer.

So if you want to change a pointer itself then passing it by reference means passing a pointer to the pointer the same way as it was done in the function above only now the type of the original variable `p` is `int *` instead of `int`.

That is if you have a declaration like this

```
T x;
```

where `T` is some type (as for example `int` or `int *`) then to pass the variable by reference you need to use a function argument expression like `&x`. that will have the type `T *`. If `T` is equivalent to the type `int *` then you need to use an argument expression of the type `int **`.