# unable to create new node where head pointer points to in c?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

say I have the following code for inserting a node at the end to a linkedlist:

```
int main() {
    struct Node* head = NULL;
    newNode(head, 1);
    newNode(head, 2);
    newNode(head, 3);
    print(head);
    return 0;
}
void newNode(struct Node* head, int val) {
    struct Node* curr_p = head;
    struct Node* new_p = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new_p->data = val;
    new_p->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL) {
        curr_p = new_p;
        // printf("head %d \n", head->data); 
    }
    else{
        while (curr_p->next != NULL) {
            curr_p = curr_p->next;
        }
        curr_p->next = new_p;
    }
}
void print(struct Node* head) {
    struct Node* curr_p = head;
    while (curr_p != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", curr_p->data);
        curr_p = curr_p->next;
    }
}
```

It appears what causes the error is in the if statement block where `head == NULL`, the head node pointer seems to unable to point to new node. I always ended up with a *segmentation fault*. any reason for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the reason for using a double pointer when adding a node in a linked list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271647/what-is-the-reason-for-using-a-double-pointer-when-adding-a-node-in-a-linked-lis)

Comment: what do you mean? I am not using pointer to pointer

Comment: But you should. Read that question and the answers

Comment: Over half of the LL posts in the C tag have this issue:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that your fault is that you are passing the head pointer in value not in reference so the code doesn't change it's value because it just copies the pointer 
so your code should look like this

```
newNode(struct Node** head , int val ) {
struct Node* curr_p = *head;
/*

*/
if(curr_p == NULL ) {
*head = new_p;

}/*....*/
    }
```

and in the main

```
newNode(&head,1)
```

and the finale code would be

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node * next;
};
    void newNode(struct Node** head, int val) {

        struct Node* curr_p = *head;
        struct Node* new_p =malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new_p->data = val;
    new_p->next = NULL;
    if ( curr_p == NULL) {
        *head = new_p;
        // printf("head %d \n", head->data);
    }
    else{
        while (curr_p->next != NULL) {
            curr_p = curr_p->next;
        }
        curr_p->next = new_p;
    }
}
void print(struct Node* head) {
    struct Node* curr_p = head;
    while (curr_p != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", curr_p->data);
        curr_p = curr_p->next;
    }
}
int main() {
    struct Node* head = NULL;
    newNode(&head, 1);
    newNode(&head, 2);
    newNode(&head, 3);
    print(head);
    return 0;
}
```

and actually you don't have to use curr_p in the print function because the head pointer in the print function it's just a copy of the head pointer of the main function so it wouldn't change it's value if you do something like `head = head->next ;` in the print function .

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified that where you are getting segmentation fault but my strong guess is that you would be getting at - `printf("head %d \n", head->data);`. Why? Because with your present code `head` is NULL (*that's what you are passing from your `main` method*) and then you try to de-reference a NULL then you WILL segmentation fault.

**You must only de-reference a valid pointer. If the pointer variable is holding NULL or some uninitialized/default value then de-referencing it will result in segmentation fault.**

Below is the fixed IF block.

```
if (head == NULL) {
    head = new_p;
    printf("head %d \n", head->data); 
}
```

Comment: With this line `struct Node* curr_p = head;` you are assigning NULL to `curr_p`. Then you were really never setting the `head` so with each invocation of `newNode`, both `head` and `curr_p` were always NULL. You would have got the segmentation fault on first invocation of `newNode`because of the reason I outlined above (*put some `printf` and you can confirm the same*). With the code change I am suggesting, basically you are setting the `head`, this will not only prevent segmentation fault, but will ensure that node is appended at the last of the list, on subsequent invocation of `newNode` ..

Comment: So, any news? Does it answer your queries?