# Recursion and linked lists in C

Tags: c, file, recursion

I'm working to create a function that takes in a path and reads all the files within it and creates a linked lists. Reading the directory works well but I'm having difficulty creating and storing the relevant information in a linked list for use later.

Heres the structure I'm using currently:

```
typedef struct searchPool searchPool;
struct searchPool{

    char * path;
    char * fileName;
    char *pathFile;

    searchPool * next;

};
```

The function to create a new element of the type 'SearchPool' is defined as such:

```
searchPool * mallocStructPool (char * path, char * fileName, char * filePath ) {

    searchPool * element = (searchPool*)malloc(sizeof(searchPool));
    element->path = malloc(sizeof(char * ));
    element->fileName = malloc(sizeof(char * ));
    element->pathFile = malloc(sizeof(char * ));

    element->path = path;
    element->fileName = fileName;
    element->pathFile = filePath;

    element->next = NULL;

    return element;
}
```

Finally the recursive function that take the list's head is written as such (code commented if you scroll to the right):

```
void listDir(char * path, searchPool * head){
    DIR * d = opendir(path);        // open the path

    searchPool * element;                                                                   // create new Element of type SearchPool
    struct dirent * dir;                                                                    // for the directory entries

    while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {                                                    // if we were able to read somehting from the directory
        if(dir-> d_type != DT_DIR) {                                                        // if the type is not directory just print it with blue

            char * s = malloc(sizeof(char*)+1);                                             // variable to concatenate
            s = concat(path, dir->d_name);                                                  // concatenate path and filename together
            //printf("%s\n",s);

            element = mallocStructPool(dir->d_name, path, s);                               // malloc new element and set variables

            head->next = element;
            element->next = NULL;

            free(s);

        } else 
        if(dir -> d_type == DT_DIR && strcmp(dir->d_name,".")!=0 && strcmp(dir->d_name,"..")!=0 ) {// if it is a directory
            char d_path[255];                                                               // here I am using sprintf which is safer than strcat
            sprintf(d_path, "%s/%s", path, dir->d_name);
            listDir(d_path, element);                                                       // recall with the new path
        }
    }
    closedir(d);                                                                            // finally close the directory
}
```

The problem is that when the function listDir() is called it only ends up printing the first path that I give it in it's parameters and the rest is ignored. Do I have to return the new element in listDir() after each run? I don't see where I'm going wrong.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You are using `malloc(sizeof(char*))` incorrectly, leaking memory.

Comment: @EOF is defined by (char * )malloc(sizeof(char * ))?

Comment: @user100000 I re-evaluated. So you have a head outside the function. Call it h_ptr1. You pass it to your function, which makes a copy. Call that h_ptr2. You add several elements to the *copy*, h_ptr2. You return, and you've lost access to h_ptr2, leaving only the h_ptr1 (still points to NULL) and a memory leak. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271647/what-is-the-reason-for-using-a-double-pointer-when-adding-a-node-in-a-linked-lis

Comment: @synchronizer I didnt realize I was making a copy of head when I was passing it to my listDir function. Ill look into this. Thank you.

Comment: You should listen to EOF's advice though.

Comment: the return type from the heap allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) is `void*` which can be assigned to any other pointer..   casting the returned type just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain..  Suggest remove the cast of the returned value from `malloc()`

Comment: these three lines need to be eliminated: `element->path = malloc(sizeof(char * ));
    element->fileName = malloc(sizeof(char * ));
    element->pathFile = malloc(sizeof(char * ));`

Comment: suggest replacing: `element->path = path;
    element->fileName = fileName;
    element->pathFile = filePath;`  with `element->path = strdup(path);
    element->fileName = strdup(fileName);
    element->pathFile = filePath;`    plus check (!=NULL) each call to `strdup()` to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: these two lines: `char * s = malloc(sizeof(char*)+1);                                             // variable to concatenate
            s = concat(path, dir->d_name);`   would be much better written as: `char *s = malloc( strlen(path)+strlen(dir->d_name)+1 ); // check also that malloc successful   sprintf( s, "%s", path ); strcat(  s, dir->d_name );`

Comment: this line: `element->next = NULL;` is already done in the function: `mallocstructpool()`

Comment: this line: `head->next = element;` keeps overlaying the same 'head->next` with each successive pointer, resulting in the earlier pointer being lost.  This is 1) not how to link (other than the first) struct instance together and 2) results in a memory leak

Comment: in function: `listDir()`, strongly suggest that the parameter `head` be passed as  a `searchPool ** head`  so the callers' 'head' pointer can be updated with the first searchPool struct instance.  After that, either append to the end of the linked list or insert at the beginning of the linked list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code don't make sense. You don't need to allocate a struct **and** his members. Plus don't [cast the return of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). You don't check the return of `malloc()`. And you don't copy the strings.

In your second function you should return the linked list and check return function of `opendir()`.

Here a example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>

typedef struct searchPool searchPool;
struct searchPool {
  char *path;
  char *fileName;
  char *pathFile;
  searchPool *next;
};

static searchPool *mallocStructPool(char *path, char *fileName) {

  searchPool *element = malloc(sizeof *element);
  if (element == NULL) {
    goto error;
  }

  size_t path_size = strlen(path);
  element->path = malloc(path_size + 1);
  if (element->path == NULL) {
    goto free_element;
  }

  size_t fileName_size = strlen(fileName);
  element->fileName = malloc(fileName_size + 1);
  if (element->fileName == NULL) {
    goto free_path;
  }

  element->pathFile = malloc(path_size + 1 + fileName_size + 1);
  if (element->pathFile == NULL) {
    goto free_fileName;
  }

  memcpy(element->path, path, path_size);
  element->path[path_size] = '\0';

  memcpy(element->fileName, fileName, fileName_size);
  element->fileName[fileName_size] = '\0';

  memcpy(element->pathFile, path, path_size);
  element->pathFile[path_size] = '/';
  memcpy(element->pathFile + path_size + 1, fileName, fileName_size);
  element->pathFile[path_size + 1 + fileName_size] = '\0';

  return element;
free_fileName:
  free(element->fileName);
free_path:
  free(element->path);
free_element:
  free(element);
error:
  return NULL;
}

searchPool *listDir(char *path);

static searchPool *listDir_aux(char *path, struct dirent *dirent) {
  if (dirent->d_type == DT_DIR && dirent->d_type != DT_LNK &&
      strcmp(dirent->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(dirent->d_name, "..") != 0) {
    size_t path_size = strlen(path);
    size_t name_size = strlen(dirent->d_name);
    char *d_path = malloc(path_size + 1 + name_size + 1);
    if (d_path == NULL) {
      return NULL;
    }

    memcpy(d_path, path, path_size);
    d_path[path_size] = '/';
    memcpy(d_path + path_size + 1, dirent->d_name, name_size);
    d_path[path_size + 1 + name_size] = '\0';

    searchPool *ret = listDir(d_path);

    free(d_path);

    return ret;
  }
  return mallocStructPool(path, dirent->d_name);
}

searchPool *listDir(char *path) {
  printf("%s\n", path);
  DIR *dir = opendir(path);
  if (dir == NULL) {
    perror("dir()");
    return NULL;
  }

  searchPool *head = NULL;

  struct dirent *dirent;
  while ((dirent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
    searchPool *elem = listDir_aux(path, dirent);
    if (elem != NULL) {
      elem->next = head;
      head = elem;
    }
  }
  closedir(dir);

  return head;
}

int main(void) {
  searchPool *head = listDir("/tmp");
  searchPool *tmp;
  for (searchPool *elem = head; elem != NULL; elem = tmp) {
    printf("%s, %s, %s\n", elem->path, elem->fileName, elem->pathFile);
    free(elem->path);
    free(elem->fileName);
    free(elem->pathFile);
    tmp = elem->next;
    free(elem);
  }
}
```

Comment: Use of `goto` has its limited usefulnesses.  Error handle like this is one of them.

Comment: @Stargateur This function works well but doesn't print out all the files in the subfolder. Since you separated the listDir into 2 functions I don't know where to look to fix this. Can you help me please?

Comment: @user100000 this work for me http://rextester.com/SRCHF77522. You can change the behavior in `listDir_aux()` in the if you have the recursive else you add the file in the list.

Comment: @Stargateur I realised I asked my question a little wrong. EN faite, I would like to print the files inside every directory too. Where in ListDirAux can I do this?

Comment: @Stargateur in listDir_aux if I put the line (before the IF) `if(dirent-> d_type != DT_DIR) 
   printf("%s\n", dirent->d_name);` then it shows the file names as well but I would like to add this to the linked list in fileName. Can you help me please?

Comment: @user100000 This information is already in your linked list in `fileName` member.

Answer (score 0):

To add an element to the tail

```
 searchPool *ptr;
 searchPool *prev = 0;
 searchPool *head = something;

 for(ptr = head; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next)
   prev = ptr;
 element->next = 0;
 prev->next = element;
```

To add to the head (faster)

```
 element->next = head;
 head = element;
```

Note head is not stable now.

To add one after the head

```
element->next = head->next;
head->next = element
```

Note that head is now probably  a dummy node without any
data in it, which exists for the sake of having a stable
and constant "head" pointer to the linked list;