# Go: **Type pointer

Tags: pointers, go

In [tutorial](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1) is written:

> The type `*T` is a pointer to a `T` value. The `&` operator generates
>   a pointer to its operand.

I am just playing around with pointers in Go and have following:

```
example := 42

p:=&example
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(&p)) // **int
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(*p)) // int
```

So if I got it correctly, `&p` is a pointer to a pointer to an int value.

[image: pointer memory scheme]

What is use of **Type in the Go language?

Comment: Just as with `*T` you can change the value of `p` by passing `&p` to a function that then changes the pointed-to value.

Comment: "What is use of **Type in the Go language?" the same as in C or any other language with pointers, e.g. for removal in linked lists.

Comment: The question, "What is use of **Type in the Go language?", is too broad. The simple answer is whenever it's useful. @Volker gave you just one example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pointer allows you to pass around a memory address, so that multiple scopes can use the same *address*, and you can change the *value* at that address without changing the address; effectively allowing you to share memory. A *pointer to a pointer* allows you to pass around the address to a memory address, so that multiple scopes can use it and you can change the *address pointed to* by the shared reference. With a normal pointer, if you change the address of the pointer, any other copies of that pointer held elsewhere will become "disconnected" - they will no longer point to the same value.

For example, you might have two variables being operated on in separate workers, and a central reference you want to be able to switch back and forth between them. A pointer to a pointer is one way to achieve this; the central reference can be changed to point to the pointer used by any of the workers. Each worker would hold a pointer to a value which it would operate on normally, without needing to know if the central reference points to its pointer or not.

Or, as @Volker noted, the canonical example of the linked list. [Here is an example in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271647/what-is-the-reason-for-using-a-double-pointer-when-adding-a-node-in-a-linked-lis) but the pointer logic is the same in Go.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple demonstration of the concept of a chain of pointers:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    i := 42
    fmt.Printf("i: %[1]T %[1]d\n", i)
    p := &i
    fmt.Printf("p: %[1]T %[1]p\n", p)
    j := *p
    fmt.Printf("j: %[1]T %[1]d\n", j)
    q := &p
    fmt.Printf("q: %[1]T %[1]p\n", q)
    k := **q
    fmt.Printf("k: %[1]T %[1]d\n", k)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/WL2M1jp1T3

Output:

```
i: int 42
p: *int 0x10410020
j: int 42
q: **int 0x1040c130
k: int 42
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you got it correctly.

As to "what use", it's the same as everywhere else: you use a pointer in these cases:

- A variable has to be changed in some other code —
  typically another function, — and so you pass a pointer to the memory
  occupied by that variable to that function so it's able to update
  that memory via that address.
- A value is too large to be passed around fast enough by copying it.

A pointer to a pointer is a bit of a pathological case *for Go,*
but still this can be used in the first case: when you want some function
to change the value of a pointer variable your code controls.