# compiler requires to dereferenciate once when I actually need to do it twice. "assigning to struct from incompatible type; remove * "

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct, linked-list

I have the following code. **I know** that is wrong, but the thing is that I dont get ***why***. Below I explain my doubts.

```
#include <stdio.h>


struct mychar {
    char value;
    struct mychar *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct mychar Mychar;


void insert(Mychar **, char );    // line 19
void printlist(Mychar **);


int main(){
    Mychar *startPtr = NULL;

    insert(&startPtr, 'b');

    printlist(&startPtr);

}


void insert(Mychar **sPtr, char myvalue){
    Mychar *newlinkPtr = calloc(1, sizeof(Mychar));

    if (**sPtr == NULL){    // if I put two ** I get errors
        newlinkPtr->value = myvalue;
        newlinkPtr->nextPtr = **sPtr;    // same here
        **sPtr = newlinkPtr;    // same here
    }
}


void printlist(Mychar **startPtr){
    printf("%c\n", *startPtr->value);    // get error
}
```

Here are the errors:

```
liste_collegate.c:29:13: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('Mychar' (aka 'struct mychar') and 'void *')
        if (**sPtr == NULL){
            ~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~
liste_collegate.c:31:23: error: assigning to 'struct mychar *' from incompatible type 'Mychar' (aka 'struct mychar'); remove *
                newlinkPtr->nextPtr = **sPtr;
                                    ^ ~~~~~~
liste_collegate.c:32:10: error: assigning to 'Mychar' (aka 'struct mychar') from incompatible type 'Mychar *' (aka 'struct mychar *'); dereference with *
                **sPtr = newlinkPtr;
                       ^ ~~~~~~~~~~
                         *
liste_collegate.c:38:26: error: member reference base type 'Mychar *' (aka 'struct mychar *') is not a structure or union
        printf("%c\n", *startPtr->value);
```

**My doubts**:

- Why if in the arguments of `insert` function I write `**sPtr`, then in the if block **I have to** use `*sPtr`, otherwise it gives me error? Shoudn't `**sPtr` be equal to NULL, since I have put NULL value inside it in the main? In the `main()` , when I call `insert` in line 19, I send there **the address &** of `startPtr`, so to access to its value NULL in the `insert` function, I should put a `*` to actually reach the pointer, and another `*` to actually reach the NULL value..
- In `printlist` function, pretty much the same doubts of before. If I "send" to `printlist` the address of the first pointer of the linked list, to actually access the first structure, shouldn't I dereferenciate to actually reach  the struct address, and then dereferenciate again with `->` to control the pointer of that structure to get "value"?

Comment: I don't think anybody but you can explain your doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First for your `insert` function:

```
void insert(Mychar **sPtr, char myvalue){
    Mychar *newlinkPtr = calloc(1, sizeof(Mychar));

    if (**sPtr == NULL){    // if I put two ** I get errors
        newlinkPtr->value = myvalue;
        newlinkPtr->nextPtr = **sPtr;    // same here
        **sPtr = newlinkPtr;    // same here
    }
}
```

`sPtr` has type `Mychar **`: pointer to pointer.

`*sPtr` has type `Mychar *`: pointer to type `Mychar`.

Now when you use `**sPtr` has type `Mychar`: a value with type `Mychar`.

`NULL` is used for pointer not for value. So if you want to compare, you can compare either `sPtr` with `NULL` or `*sptr` with `NULL`. You should not compare the value `**sPtr` with `NULL`. BTW, your function can become like:

```
void insert(Mychar **sPtr, char myvalue){
    Mychar *newlinkPtr = calloc(1, sizeof(Mychar));
    if (!newlinkPtr) {return;} // you should check the return value of calloc funciton because it may be failed

    if (*sPtr == NULL) {  
        newlinkPtr->value = myvalue;
        newlinkPtr->nextPtr = *sPtr;   
        *sPtr = newlinkPtr;  
    }
}
```

For print function:

```
void printlist(Mychar **startPtr){
    printf("%c\n", *startPtr->value);    // get error
}
```

`*startPtr->value` should change to `(*startPtr)->value`.

But, with print function, you do not need to use pointer to pointer, because in this function, you do not change or update anything. You can use pointer as:

```
void printlist(Mychar *startPtr){
    printf("%c\n", startPtr->value);
}
```

If you do that, in main function, when you call print function:

```
printlist(startPtr);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. ! One question: why in the linked lists do I need to pass the address of the pointer with `&` to `insert` function ?

Comment: with `insert` function, instead of return HEAD pointer (it's `startPtr` in your code) we pass the argument as the pointer to HEAD pointer. For your case, In main function, you declare `Mychar *startPtr`, it means `startPtr` has type `Mychar *`, and in the declaration of `insert` function, you use pointer to pointer (the type is `Mychar**`), so you have to use `& `: `insert(&startPtr, 'b');`. You can see more info at the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271647/what-is-the-reason-for-using-a-double-pointer-when-adding-a-node-in-a-linked-lis

Answer (score 0):

> "Shoudn't `**sPtr` be equal to `NULL`, since I have put `NULL` value inside it in the main?"

No.

`NULL` is a macro for a null pointer; It is used for pointers only, not it´s referenced objects (unless the referenced object is also a pointer and you want to check if for `NULL`, but that´s not the point here).

`**sPtr` is a pointer to pointer to type `Mychar`, actually a struct. If you dereference `sPtr` ( means `*sPtr`) you access the pointer it is pointing to (actually `startPtr` in main), which is correct for checking `NULL`.

If you use `if (**sPtr == NULL)` you attempt to dereference `startPtr` - a `NULL` pointer - itself, which is invalid and attempt to check the object `startPtr` is pointing to (actually nothing) for `NULL`, but not `startPtr`.

> "Shouldn't I dereferenciate to actually reach the struct address, and then dereference again with `->` to control the pointer of that structure to get "value"?"

You need to dereference the pointer to pointer `startPtr` first and thereafter access `value` by `->`. Use `(*startPtr)->value)` instead.

---

Side notes:

1. Always check the return value of a memory-management function, if the allocation were successful.

F.e.:

```
Mychar *newlinkPtr = calloc(1, sizeof(Mychar));
if (newlinkPtr == NULL)
{
    fputs("Allocation failed!", stderr);
    exit(1);
}
```

2. (Probably  just a copy & paste mistake but worth to mention) - You forgot to `#include <stdlib.h>`, which is necessary to use `calloc()`.

---

Result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct mychar {
    char value;
    struct mychar *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct mychar Mychar;


void insert(Mychar **, char );    
void printlist(Mychar **);


int main (void) {
    Mychar *startPtr = NULL;

    insert(&startPtr, 'b');

    printlist(&startPtr);

}


void insert(Mychar **sPtr, char myvalue){
    Mychar *newlinkPtr = calloc(1, sizeof(Mychar));
    if (newlinkPtr == NULL)
    {
        fputs("Allocation failed!", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (*sPtr == NULL){    
        newlinkPtr->value = myvalue;
        newlinkPtr->nextPtr = *sPtr;    
        *sPtr = newlinkPtr;    
    }
}


void printlist(Mychar **startPtr){
    printf("%c\n", (*startPtr)->value);    
}
```

Output:

```
b
```

Comment: @Mnkisd I don´t know. The first maybe was because my answer wasn´t fulfilled at that point of time. The second I guess just someone who followed the action.  I can´t see that my answer has a fault. If they see something, convention is to hint and not to only downvote. Maybe even asymphatics? IDK.