# HashTable - Array of Linked List C++ - Remove Function, Delete a Node

Tags: c++, arrays

This is my first post so bear with me. I have a program that is an Array of Linked Lists that I'm mostly done with except for one thing, I get a segmentation fault in my Remove and Remove Help Functions. I only get segmentation Fault when I try to remove a Node that is the "head" of the Linked List in the Array. Is there any way to fix this without creating a Head?

I'm also a Student so sorry if I got some terms wrong.

`table.h` file:

```
#pragma once
#include "website.h"
#include <fstream>

class Table
{
    public:
        Table();
        ~Table();
        void    insert      (const Website& aWebsite);
        bool    retrieve    (char * topic_keyword,
                            Website all_matches [], int& num_found);
        bool    edit        (char * newReview, int newRating, char * topic_keyword);
        bool    remove      ();
        int     getSize     () const;
        void    print       (ostream& out) const;
        void    loadFile    (const char * fileName);

    private:
        struct Node
        {
            Node(const Website& aWebsite)
            {
                data = new Website(aWebsite);
                next = nullptr;
            }
            ~Node()
            {
                delete data;
            }
            Website * data;
            Node * next;
        };
    
        static const int CAP = 5;
        Node ** aTable;
        int size;

        int     hashFunction    (const char * key) const;
        void    destroy         (Node **& myTable);
        void    destroy         (Node *& first);
        void    print           (ostream& out, Node * first,
                                int currPosition) const;
        bool    removeHelp      (Node * curr);  
};
```

`table.cpp` file:

```
#include "table.h"

Table::Table() : size(0)
{
    aTable = new Node * [CAP];
    for(int index = 0; index < CAP; index++)
        aTable[index] = nullptr;
}

Table::~Table()
{
    if(aTable) 
        destroy(this->aTable);
}

void    Table::destroy      (Node **& myTable)
{
    for(int index = 0; index < CAP; index++)
    {
        destroy(myTable[index]);
    }
    delete [] myTable;
}

void    Table::destroy      (Node *& first)
{
    if(first)
    {
        destroy(first->next);
        delete first;
    }
}

int     Table::hashFunction (const char * key) const
{
    int total = 0;
    const char * ptr = key;
    while( *ptr != '\0')
    {
            total += * ptr;
            ptr++;
    }
    return total % CAP;
}

void    Table::insert       (const Website& aWebsite)
{
    int index = hashFunction(aWebsite.getWebsiteName());
    Node * newNode = new Node(aWebsite);
    newNode->next = aTable[index];
    aTable[index] = newNode;
    size++;
}

bool    Table::retrieve 
        (char * topic_keyword, Website all_matches[], int& num_found)
{
    int index = hashFunction(topic_keyword);
    
    Node * curr = aTable[index];

    while(curr && strcmp(topic_keyword, curr->data->getWebsiteName()) != 0 )
    {
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    
    if(!curr)
        return false;

    all_matches[index] = *(curr->data);
    num_found++;
        
    return true;
}

bool    Table::edit         (char * newReview, int newRating, char * topic_keyword)
{
    int index = hashFunction(topic_keyword);
    
    Node * curr = aTable[index];

    while(curr && strcmp(topic_keyword, curr->data->getWebsiteName())!=0)
    {
         curr = curr->next;
    }
    
    if(!curr)
        return false;

    curr->data->setWebsiteReview(newReview);
    curr->data->setWebsiteRating(newRating);

    return true;

}

bool    Table::remove       ()
{
    for(int index = 0; index < CAP; index++)
    {
        removeHelp(aTable[index]);
    }
    return true;    
}

bool    Table::removeHelp   (Node * curr)
{
    Node * prev = nullptr;
    while(curr && (curr->data->getWebsiteRating()) != 1)
    {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    if(!curr)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if(!prev)
        {
            Node * temp = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
            delete temp;
        }
        else{
            prev->next = curr->next;
            delete curr;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int     Table::getSize      () const
{
    return size;
}

void    Table::print        (ostream& out) const
{
    for(int index = 0; index < CAP; index++)
    {
        out << "Chain # " << index << "..." << endl;
        out << endl;
        print(out, aTable[index], 0);
    }
}

void    Table::print        (ostream& out, Node * currFirst, int currPosition) const
{
    if(currFirst)
    {
        out << *(currFirst->data) << endl;
        print(out, currFirst->next, ++currPosition);
    }
}

void    Table::loadFile     (const char * fileName)
{
    ifstream    in;
    const int   MAX_CHAR = 101;
    
    char        name    [MAX_CHAR];
    char        address [MAX_CHAR];
    char        summary [MAX_CHAR];
    char        review  [MAX_CHAR];
    int         rating;

    Website     aWebsite;

    in.open(fileName);
    if(!in)
    {
        cerr << "Failed to Open!" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    
    in.get(name, MAX_CHAR, ';');
    while(!in.eof())
    {
        in.get();
        in.get(address, MAX_CHAR, ';');
        in.get();
        in.get(summary, MAX_CHAR, ';');
        in.get();
        in.get(review, MAX_CHAR, ';');
        in.get();
        in >> rating;
        in.get();
        
        aWebsite.setWebsiteName     (name);
        aWebsite.setWebsiteAddress  (address);
        aWebsite.setWebsiteSummary  (summary);
        aWebsite.setWebsiteReview   (review);
        aWebsite.setWebsiteRating   (rating);

        this->insert(aWebsite);
        in.get();
        in.get(name, MAX_CHAR, ';');
    }
    in.close();
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Table& aTable)
{
    aTable.print(out);
    return out;
}
```

Visual:

```
Node * [] -> Array 
        index [Pointer * ] -> [ Node *]
        index [Pointer * ] -> [ Node *]
        index [Pointer * ] -> [ Node *]
```

Comment: hi there, maybe this can help you.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/delete-a-linked-list-node-at-a-given-position/

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271647/what-is-the-reason-for-using-a-double-pointer-when-adding-a-node-in-a-linked-lis

Comment: Oops, that is a lot of code... But it still lacks a minimal *scenario* (what to insert and remove) to exhibit the problem. In fact what we need to be able to help you is a [mre].