# C++ Set values for members of a struct**

Tags: c++, struct, config, members

I've defined in my `foo.h` the following variables

```
#define APILONG          long
#define APIDOUBLE        double                   
#define APISTRING        const char*
```

And also the following struct

```
struct SetupData
{
  APISTRING customerName;
  APIDOUBLE quantity;
  APILONG startDate;

};
```

Now, in my `foo.cpp` i have the following method where I need to assign values to the members of the struct that are being pulled from a `.config` file.

```
APILONG doSomething(APISTRING* setupOrder, APILONG* setupActive, struct SetupData** setupData)
{
//load config file
Config config("rommel.config");

//assign a string value to APISTRING* (No issue here.)
*setupOrder= config.pString("setupOrder").c_str();

//assign a value (No issue here, atleast not that I know of..)
*setupActive = config.pDouble("setupActive");

//assign values to members of struct**
(*setupData)->customerName = config.pString("setupDataCustomerName").c_str();
(*setupData)->quantity = config.pDouble("setupDataQuantity");
(*setupData)->startDate = config.pDouble("setupDataStartDate");

//do other stuff..
}
```

When I compile and rebuild it does not give me any error messages. But when I try to run the actual program it crashes. (Am using Dev-C++, Visual Studio was causing problems..)
 I do however get a chance to see the values assigned before it crashes and it looks like the values are not being assigned (Null or strange characters).

I've tried variations of the 
`(*setupData)->startDate ..` 
line and also I have tried declaring the struct in the method like the following, but to no avail.

```
    struct SetupData stpData;
    *setupData = &stpData;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I previously posted another question which is related to this, it contains some pretty useful information aswell. I'll leave the link in case it helps. ["C++ Set value for a char**"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31775571/c-set-value-for-a-char)

Comment: What does `config.pString` return? I bet it is a temporary `std::string`.

Comment: First, you need to correct your spelling of "ApiLongstocking".

Comment: Why use `#define`? What does it add? Just makes code less readable

Comment: @EdHeal I cant really modify it, this is a legacy code ive been given to work with.
@DarkFalcon config.pString is defined in config.cpp as: `string Config::pString(string name) {..}`
@JerryCoffin lol i cant find the typo..

Answer (score 0):

The `config` object is local to the `doSomething` function.

The `setupOrder` pointer points to what appears to be a
member of the `config` object.

The `config` object will go out of scope at the end of the `doSomething` function and can be de-allocated at that point.
At that point, what the `setupOrder` pointer "points" to 
might no longer be valid.

It is a good idea to make sure that after the call to  `doSomething` ends,
that all the pointers still point to objects that still exist.

You may have already done this, but I just wanted to check.

Comment: Yes, well I've assigned values to other objects in other methods like I'm doing in this method without any problems, the problem is when i try to assign values to members of a struct**

Comment: @DavidA. - No, if A B's description is correct, the problem is that the code *seems to work* sometimes. The value of a `c_str()` is only valid as long as the `std::string` that supplied it is unchanged. If the string is modified or destroyed, you end up with a dangling pointer.

Comment: @BoPersson I believe I understand what your saying, it's just that what throws me off is that this only happens with members of data structs. Any suggestions on how to work around this? Maybe assign values to other variables within the scope first and then assign them to the struct members?